# How do I avoid copy-pasting code blocks when only minor things need changes?

Tags: c++

This is difficult for me to put into words, but say I have some function:

```
a = a + b;
printf("HI THERE");
b = a + c;
```

(pretend this is 30 lines instead of 3 lines).  Now say I want to do the exact same thing again later on, except instead of printing "HI THERE" I print "HO THERE".  What I currently do is copy paste all the lines of this function just to change HI THERE to HO THERE.  This isn't very elegant for large code blocks.

I know one solution might be like:

```
adder_function(1);
adder_function(2);

void adder_fuction(int input) {
   a = a + b;
   printer_function(input);
   b = a + c;
}

void printer_function(int input) {
   if (input == 1) printf("HI THERE");
   if (input == 2) printf("HO THERE");
}
```

But this seems to be inelegant as well for more complex blocks of code.  Any ideas for better solutions?

EDIT: Just to show what it is I'm doing, here's the code in question (you can see that almost nothing changes between the blocks except .input and .output and the printf statements):

```
found=line.find("INPUTS");
if (found == 0) {
    inputfound = true;
    found = line.find_first_of(":");

    if (found == string::npos) { 
        printf("BAD NETLIST INPUT DECLARATION\n\r"); 
        exit(1);
    }

    found = line.find_first_not_of("\n\t ",found+1);

    if (found == string::npos) {
        printf("BAD NETLIST INPUT DECLARATION\n\r");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        temp_node_name += line[found];
        for (i = found+1; i < line.size(); i++) {
            if ( isalnum(line[i]) || isspace(line[i]) ) {
                if ( isalnum(line[i]) )
                    temp_node_name += line[i];
                if ( isspace(line[i]) || i == line.size() - 1 ) {
                    if (!temp_node_name.empty()) {
                        if (determine_uniqueness(temp_node_name)) {
                            nodes.push_back(dummy_node);
                            nodes.at(id_counter).name_in_netlist = temp_node_name;
                            nodes.at(id_counter).input = true;
                            temp_node_name.erase();
                            id_counter++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                printf("BAD NETLIST INPUT DECLARATION\n\r");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("NETLIST INPUT DECLARATION OK\n\r");
    continue;
}
```

SEPARATE CODE BLOCK THAT IS COPY PASTED

```
found=line.find("OUTPUTS");
if (found == 0){
    outputfound = true;
    found = line.find_first_of(":");

    if (found == string::npos) {
        printf("BAD NETLIST OUTPUT DECLARATION\n\r"); 
        exit(1);
    }

    found = line.find_first_not_of("\n\t ",found+1);
    if (found == string::npos) {
        printf("BAD NETLIST OUTPUT DECLARATION\n\r");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        temp_node_name += line[found];
        for (i = found+1; i < line.size(); i++) {
            if ( isalnum(line[i]) || isspace(line[i]) ) {
                if ( isalnum(line[i]) )
                    temp_node_name += line[i];
                if ( isspace(line[i]) || i == line.size() - 1 ) {
                    if (!temp_node_name.empty()) {
                        if (determine_uniqueness(temp_node_name)) {
                            nodes.push_back(dummy_node);
                            nodes.at(id_counter).name_in_netlist = temp_node_name;
                            **nodes.at(id_counter).output = true;**
                            temp_node_name.erase();
                            id_counter++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                printf("BAD NETLIST OUTPUT DECLARATION\n\r");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("NETLIST OUTPUT DECLARATION OK\n\r");
    continue;
}
```

Comment: What is your wider goal?

Comment: My wider goal is to not copy and paste 20 lines of code (or more) just to change 1 or 2 lines.  It seems like doing so needlessly increases the code-space when some sort of conditional function template can be used.

Comment: This is plain C, nothing to do with C++

Comment: @Antonio: But the answer is wildly different depending on whether this is C++ or not. C++ has templates, C has only preprocessor.

Comment: The code I provided is just an example.  I'm saying I have C++ functionality available if it helps to solve the problem.

Comment: @Jan: the concrete example the OP exposes is solvable just using a function that takes a `char*` parameter instead of an `int`. The use of templates is far from the simplest solution.

Comment: Now it's C++. Not the best style, but definitely C++ :)

Comment: I'd like to note that, in your (newer) example code, `printf("message\n\r")` is almost certainly wrong. `stdout` is almost certainly open in text mode, and the C standard states that, for files open in text mode (rather than binary mode), the character `\n` is translated to the platform's newline sequence (if any such translation is required). You should rarely have to worry about EOL characters in anything but OS-specific level code (i.e. using the Windows API and such).

Comment: @Chris: besides the fact that the sequence for end of line in Windows platforms is `\r\n` and not `\n\r`.

Comment: @Antonio: Yes, but it's an example. If the code is more complicated than that, it's important to know what options there are.

Comment: Also, you appear to have a lot of variable names, but I see no declarations. Ever heard of variable scope?

Comment: @Antonio - All the more reason to let the standard library do it for you. ;)

Comment: @Chris Jeezus H Christ It's a CODE SEGMENT not the whole program.

Comment: @Anonymous: I think Chris and some other folks as me would appreciate it not to have to assume the type of your variables.

Comment: @Anonymous - It is, but a few of those variables appear to be temporary variables that shouldn't need to keep existing after a certain scope (unless they do and I just can't see the code that needs them). Rather than declaring a temporary once, and reusing it ten times in your program, you should declare it in the innermost scope you can, so that when people see that temporary the tenth time you use it, they don't have to scroll all the way back to the top to figure out what it is - its declaration is right in front of them. (The compiler will probably optimize the stack adjustments for you.)

Comment: @Anonymous Please don't get cross. Without wishing to seem rude, you have a huge amount to learn about effective software development and many experts are giving you the benefit of their expertise in their spare time for free! Concentrate on learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm late to the party so I'll only be addressing your updated code.

First off, I see you printing error messages to `stdout` (via `printf`) and then calling `exit`. Why? You should print error (and perhaps debugging) messages to `stderr` (with `fprintf(stderr, ...)` or with `perror`, though `perror` is better if a library routine fails and sets `errno`). Also, since this is C++ (not plain C), you might want to use `iostream`s instead of `*printf`. It's more C++-ish (though, as predominantly a C programmer, I prefer `*printf` myself).

Since the only difference between your two blocks of code is the string containing `INPUT` in the first and `OUTPUT` in the second, I recommend stuffing all of this into a function that, among other necessary parameters (whatever `line` is is probably one of them), takes a parameter called `bool is_input`. The first time you call this, `is_input` should be `true`, and the second time, it should be `false`.

Then, in both of your blocks of code, you can change the `printf` lines to:

```
fprintf(stderr, "BAD NETLIST %s DECLARATION\n", is_input ? "INPUT" : "OUTPUT");
```

or

```
fprintf(stderr, "NETLIST %s DECLARATION OK\n", is_input ? "INPUT" : "OUTPUT");
```

And then for the member modification write:

```
(is_input ? nodes[id_counter].input : nodes[id_counter]) = true
```

(Note that there's no need to use `.at` twice in a row with the same index - if it threw the exception once, it won't reach the second call, and if it didn't throw the first time it won't throw the second. It probably won't be a huge speedup, but it's the thought that counts?)

Last, if you need the external variables `inputfound` and `outputfound` to be set, add a `bool &found` parameter to your function, and set it to be `true` inside the function. The first time you call it, pass `inputfound`, and the second, `outputfound`.

Now your two code blocks are identical, and can be put together into one function, and called twice (once with `"INPUT"`, and once with `"OUTPUT"`). Easy.

In the future, whenever you find yourself writing a block of code that's strikingly similar to another block of code, stop rewriting (or copy-and-pasting). Copy the block of code into a new function all by itself, and replace the original block with a call to the new function. Now you can reuse that block of code as many times as you want.

Comment: The changes in the code are also where I do .input = true vs. .output = true.

And I call exit because if an error is thrown then I want the program to end completely.

Comment: @Anonymous - Regarding `exit`: I originally thought that `perror` exited for you, but I was wrong. `exit` on error is fine, but you should print error messages to `stderr`. (Or, in C++, consider using `std::cerr` or `std::clog` and C++ iostreams.) Regarding `.input` and `.output`: Ah. That makes this a little more difficult (but not impossible).

Comment: You're probably right about it being better to use stderr than printf(.  But since this is just a homework assignment and not something that is going to be going anywhere useful (I'm also not a CS major), I'm sort of "sticking with what I know".  It's just this problem of copy pasting was bugging me cause I feel there HAS to be a better way.

Comment: @Anonymous - I think I've pretty much covered all the differences between the two code blocks that would keep you from putting them into a function. (I missed the difference in the first line, but that's pretty much the same as the differences in the `fprintf` statements. I think you can figure that out.)

Comment: I'm giving you the gold.  I think you got exactly what I was trying to do and gave a solution which works (I'll test it when it's not 1 AM :) )

Answer (score 2):

Making functions is, of course, a great way to reuse code.  If you have the same code repeated in multiple places, you can make a function out of it.  If you find that you have a lot of functions doing similar things, maybe you can combine them into one function with a few extra parameters.  In the example you gave, you could do something like this:

```
void adder_function(const char * message) {
    a = a + b;
    printf("%s", message);
    b = a + c;
}

int main() {
    adder_function("HI THERE");
    adder_function("HO THERE");
}
```

I recommend that you try to avoid adding magic numbers (e.g. 1 and 2) to your source code.  It is better to use #defines or avoid that situation altogether, as I have done above.

Comment: Sorry, my example wasn't very good I suppose.  If I want to do something like node_struct.XXXXX = 2; where XXXXXX can be an arbitrary string, how would I go about doing this?  This is what I mean by "reusing code"....where the code can be anything not necessarily just printing out something different.  

Right now my only choice is to do node_struct.a = 2; and node_struct.b = 2.  This can get quite messy if it's inside 4 nested loops and I end up copy pasting 20+ lines of code.

Comment: If .a and .b are of the same type, you can pass in a pointer to them as a parameter to the function.  Do you know how to pass in a pointer and then write to it inside the function?

Comment: If the XXXXXX is always the same type, look into pointer to member, or heck, just a pointer.. and then create a function that takes a pointer to the XXXXXX.

Comment: See my edited post.  The code blocks are practically identical but I end up copy pasting them just to change all the "input" bits to "output"

Comment: Instead of `printf("%s", message)` I would recommend `puts(message)`. It'll be slightly more efficient (no parsing a format string) and will automatically include a newline at the end (unlike the `printf` example).

Comment: In C++ you would prefer using `std::string`, and for sure, you would avoid `#define`s

Answer (score 2):

Following the Single responsibility principle, you should break up your Code in smaller parts. In your example you mix up UI Code (printf) with calculation logic. Avoid this.

Since you talk in plain C Code (no C++) it is hard to give you an example of a more flexible design using common OOP patterns. But a very simple first solution for your problem is to seperate the output stuff from the calcualtion:

```
void ShowMessage(const char* msg);
int Calculate(int a, int b);

int DoTheHiThereCalculation()
{
  int c = Calculate(1, 2);
  ShowMessage("Hi THERE");
  return c;
}
```

Comment: The "wall" I'm running into is the fact that my code is a series of nested loops where the handful of changes to the code are sprinkled through multiple layers of the nest.

Comment: @Anonymus: hansmaad is right. Refactoring this code would make it much more readable (I'm still not sure what you're trying to do) and might also solve the problem you are currently trying to solve. Try to make each function do exactly one thing. Yours do both logic and output; that is called coupling and it's a very bad thing.

Comment: Your EDIT looks like a application for regex, available in boost or C++11 for example. The best code to reuse is code you did not write and don't have to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems that the various simple solutions presented here did no good, I will propose a sledgehammer (*WARNING: use with caution*)

There are two design patterns in OO languages to deal with pattern repetition:

- [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) (not to be mistaken with C++ templates)
- [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

In your case, I will recommend trying out the `Strategy` pattern, in a Dependency Injection way.

```
struct Strategy {
  virtual void setFoo(Foo& foo, int i) = 0;
  virtual void setBar(Bar& bar, int i) = 0;
};

struct A: Strategy {
  virtual void setFoo(Foo& foo, int i) { foo.a = i; }
  virtual void setBar(Bar& bar, int i) { bar.a = i; }
};

struct B: Strategy {
  virtual void setFoo(Foo& foo, int i) { foo.b = i; }
  virtual void setBar(Bar& bar, int i) { bar.b = i; }
};

void doSomething(Foo& foo, Bar& bar, Strategy& strategy) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    //
    strategy.setFoo(foo, i);
    //
    for (size_t j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
      //
      strategy.setBar(bar, j);
      //
    }
  }
}
```

You may now invoke `doSomething` with either a `A` or a `B` strategy. Example:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc == 1) { std::cerr << "usage: %prog STRAT\n"; return 1; }

  Foo foo;
  Bar bar;

  char const strat = argv[1][0];
  switch(strat) {
  case 'a': case 'A': {
    A a;
    doSomething(foo, bar, a);
    return 0;
  }
  case 'b': case 'B': {
    B b;
    doSomething(foo, bar, b);
    return 0;
  }
  default:
    std::cerr << "Unknown Strategy: " << strat << ", pick A or B\n";
    return 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a nice bit of code, but it seems like you're still copy-pasting code and just sweeping it under the rug somewhere else?

Comment: @Anonymous: Where is there copy-pasting ?

Comment: virtual void setFoo(Foo& foo, int i) { foo.b = i; }
is the same both times just with .a changed to .b

Comment: @Anonymous: Yes, indeed. OO is verbose, unfortunately. Still, you notice that instead of copying the whole block, I copied a single statement... That's the cleaner you'll get.

Comment: @Matthieu M. - An alternative templated version to avoid virtual functions (and some repetition): `struct A { template <typename T> static void set(T& foo, int i) { foo.a = i; } }; struct B { template <typename T> static void set(T& foo, int i) { foo.b = i; } }; template <typename T> doSomething(Foo& foo, Bar& bar, T tmp) { T::set(foo, 0); T::set(bar, 1); }`

Comment: @Chris Lutz: I only advise templates to people that already grok OO :)

Comment: @Matthieu - That's possibly a good idea, though I don't think templates are really an OO feature of C++.

Comment: @Chris: they are not. They are harder to understand though, both because of the syntax and the fact that they are somewhat unique to C++ so people don't have much prior exposure.

Answer (score 0):

```
const char* STR_TABLE[N] =
{
  "HI THERE",
  "HO THERE",
  ...
};


printf(STR_TABLE[n]);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to topic starter comment

> . If I want to do something like node_struct.XXXXX = 2; where XXXXXX can be an arbitrary string, how would I go about doing this?

As far as you are using c/c++ you could use macros. (look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttsbh614%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

```
#define NODE_MEMBER(x) node_struct.##x
......
NODE_MEMBER(a)
NODE_MEMBER(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the things that change (in the 2 functions) as a parameter to a function (this is the one and only function that accepts those different parameters). That way, you can do both the things in a single function.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest case: If it's just parameters of the intermediate operation that change, just pass them into the function as parameters (plain C suffices):

```
void adder_fuction(const char *text) {
    a = a + b;
    puts(text);
    b = a + c;
}
int main() {
    adder_function("HI THERE");
    adder_function("HO THERE");
}
```

Now if it's not, you'll want to pass a function. There are many ways. The first is to pass a function pointer (plain C still suffices):

```
void adder_function(void (*callback)()) {
    a = a + b;
    callback();
    b = a + c;
}
void callback1() {
    puts("HI THERE");
}
void callback2() {
    puts("HO THERE");
}
int main() {
    adder_function(&callback1);
    adder_function(&callback2);
}
```

You can of course have callback with arguments and return value. E.g.:

```
void adder_function(int (*callback)(const char *)) {
    a = a + b;
    c = c + callback("HI THERE");
    b = a + c;
}
int callback1(const char *) ...
```

Now the last option that plain C has is using the preprocessor. It should be considered an **ugly hack**, though it does have it's place if you are doing something very generic in plain C:

```
#define define_adder_function(name, code) \
     name() { \
         a = a + b; \
         code; \
         b = a + c; \
     }
```

Since C macros are not hygienic, it allows things like:

```
define_adder_function(adder_function1, c = 22) // NO semicolon here. Using preprocessor does have it's quirks
int main() {
    adder_function1();
}
```

Now C++ allows some extra options:

```
struct Callback {
    virtual void operator()(const char *) = 0;
};
void adder_function(Callback &cb) {
    a = a + b;
    cb("foo");
    b = a + c;
}
int main() {
    struct Cb : Callback {
        void operator()(const char *arg) { printf("Foo %s\n", arg); }
    } cb;
    adder_function(cb);
}
```

If you have C++11 `std::function`, either from C++0x/C++11 support in compiler, from C++ TR1 (as `std::tr1::function`) or from Boost (as `boost::function`), you can avoid declaring the virtual base class manually.

```
#include <functional>
void adder_function(std::function<void (const char *)> cb) {
    a = a + b;
    cb("foo");
    b = a + c;
}
void callback1(const char *arg) { puts(arg); }
int main() {
    struct { // You can have local structures, even with methods, but not local functions
        void operator()(const char *arg) { printf("Foo %s\n", arg); }
    } callback2;
    adder_function(&callback1); // std::function should accept either function or functor
    adder_function(callback2);
}
```

Other way to avoid virtual base class and this time also virtual dispatch (at the cost of the code being compiled twice) is (works in C++98):

```
template <typename Callback>
void adder_function(Callback cb) {

    a = a + b;
    cb("foo");
    b = a + c;
}
void callback1(const char *arg) { puts(arg); }
int main() {
    struct Callback2 { // Anonymous types can't be used in templates before C++11.
        void operator()(const char *arg) { printf("Foo %s\n", arg); }
    } callback2;
    adder_function(&callback1); // template also accepts either function pointer or functor
    adder_function(callback2);
}
```

Last if you have C++11 support in compiler (no way to do this in library, it's new syntax), you can combine the last two with the new lambda syntax:

```
int main() {
    adder_function([](const char *arg) { puts(arg) });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind, I would refactor it to break the responsibility. I would separate the parsing from the program flow that decides what to do when the input is parsed. In the enclosing function you will just call the helper, and based on the return (or exception) determine the error to show, if an error is encountered, or the variables to set. This will remove duplication from the parsing of the *netlist* (parsing is exactly the same for input and output, the only change is what the error message to be shown is and whether to set the input/output flag. Setting of the flag can be done externally, if your parser returns a sequence of *names*, then the outer code can construct the *nodes* and set the flag according to the stage of the process in which you are.

Comment: I believe you're right. I don't mean to discard your advice or sound like a prick, but for what I need to do in code I don't particularly "care" how expertly done it is simply because it doesn't matter 99% of the time.  I just need code that produces a good output and how it gets there isn't so important (can you tell I'm an engineering major? :) )

I do realize that some day in the future I MIGHT/WILL need to refactor my code and change my way of thinking, so I will keep your suggestion in mind for future reference.

Comment: @Anonymous: I am an engineer, with experience, and it is experience what dictates that things done correctly in the beginning incur in lesser costs in the long term. That being said, as long as I don't have to maintain your code, it's fine by me! :)